# Как отобразить уведомление единожды в день в строго определённое время?

Tags: java, android, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Собрался сделать напоминание пользователю типа "зайдите в игру, соберите денежки". Уведомление должно появляться каждый день ровно в 12:00. Не понимаю - оно появляется, не обращая внимания на календарь!

Вот мой MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 AlarmManager alarmManager;

 private PendingIntent alarmIntent;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ //начало onCreate

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    long timeToStart = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeToStart){
        timeToStart += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one day
    }
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToStart, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
} // конец class
```

Вот мой AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Raised",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(//что писать???);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Тест");
        builder.setContentText("Тест");
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        builder.setLights(0x0000FF,3000,2000);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(56, builder.build());
    }
}
```

И блок кода в манифесте

```
 <receiver    android:name="ru.diskrim.nebo.AlarmReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true"
      >
```

Уведомление появляется при запуске MainActivity. А должно ровно в 12:00 только когда приложение закрыто.

---

```
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);

long timeToStart = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeToStart){
    timeToStart += 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L; // one day
}
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToStart, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Теперь уведомление вообще не отображается. В 16:00 ничего не произошло. Пробовал когда приложение и открыто, и закрыто...

Comment: Вы бы попробовали локализовать проблему, и выложить только тот код, который **абсолютно необходим** для её воспроизведения. Чем больше кода вы выкладываете, тем меньше вероятность, что кому-то захочется его читать.

Comment: Сергей, обратите внимание на то, как я и @Nick Volynkin отредактировали ваш вопрос. Вопрос должен содержать свою суть в заголовке и иметь только тот код, который относится к проблеме. Как вы могли заметить, без этих существенных деталей ваш вопрос был заминусован, потом бы его закрыли и удалили. И всё из-за заголовка и простыни кода в нём. Примите это к сведению при публикации следующих вопросов, если вам и в правду нужны ответы на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Также добавьте что ваш код выведет в логи в качестве значений `timeToStart` и `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Очевидно, что у вас в момент инициализации задачи-таймера время старта меньше таки времени системы. Возможно, тут дело в привидении типов. Вы к `timeToStart` прибавляете `int`, а надо `long`. Попробуйте так: `timeToStart += 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;`

Comment: Вот это `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16)` не `16:00` !!! Путаетесь в своей собственной логике приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка скорее всего тут

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
```

Вы сбрасываете время на ноль часов текущего дня, что всегда меньше текущего времени. Поэтому это условие всегда `false`

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeToStart){
    timeToStart += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one day
}
```

И как результат, будильник всегда в прошлом и "звонит" сразу же.

Comment: Точно) Я и не заметил))) Я не ТС, если что)

Comment: А мне сразу бросилось, что коллега хочет в полночь своим пользователям уведомления слать :)

Comment: Ну, это я заметил, но подумал, что раз надо, значит надо и дальше смотреть стал)

Comment: @Юрий СПб, хаха) понятно) а как сделать чтобы уведомление появлялось в 12:00 если приложение закрыто? Подскажите пожалуйста :) я кодю в AIDE кстати

Comment: @СергейГрушин, вам надо в условии поменять местами аргументы. После этого на телефоне запустить активити, она установит аларм. Теперь, поменяв время на девайсе вы сможете увидеть уведомление.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, я бы посоветовал избавиться вообще от этого условия с телом `timeToStart +=`. Вместо этого сбрасывать календарь в 23:59.59 текущего дня, это будет стабильно всегда в будущем. Если речь идет о полночи.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, почему бы не принять ответ?