# Создание уведомлений в Android на указанную дату и время

Tags: java, android

В моем приложении нужно реализовать чтобы при добавлении растения в локальную базу данных, пользователю через 2 дня прислало что нужно его полить. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно создать планирование уведомления через два дня после добавления. Также возможно ли создать много разных уведомлений, так как растение могут добавить не одно. Буду рад любой помощи, возможно есть специальная библиотека.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отобразить уведомление единожды в день в строго определённое время?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484265/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Comment: Обратите внимание на Alarm Service https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Спасибо это помогло, если немножко разобраться и переделать всё работает, однако как я после после перезапуска телефона это уведомление не сработает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать один из планировщиков задач,

1. [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) запускает запланированные операции даже если приложение остановлено. В качестве операций используются [PendingIntents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent). 
   AlarmManager доступен с API v1, но по умолчанию не работает в Doze Mode. Для работы в Doze Mode используется метод setAndAllowWhileIdle(). Этот метод доступен с API v23.
2. [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) позволяет работать в Doze Mode и доступен с API v21. 
   Система группирует задачи, запланированные через JobScheduler. Когда появляется окно в Doze Mode, выполняется сразу несколько задач. Этот подход бережет батарейку устройства.
3. [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) – библиотека из Android Jetpack. WorkManager работает начиная с API v14. Google рекомендует использовать WorkManager вместо решений, разработанных ранее.
   Под капотом WorkManager использует JobScheduler на устройствах с API v23+. На версиях API 14 - 22 используется GCMNetworkManager или AlarmManager.

По моему мнению AlarmManager это самый простой способ, а WorkManager можно так сказать самый современный.

Comment: Вы случайно не знаете будет ли AlarmManager / WorkManager работать после перезагрузки?

Comment: С перезагрузкой не проверял, никогда. Но нашел [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558052/android-alarmmanager-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8) должно быть что надо, попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
    try {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, PlantActivity.class);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_splash)
                .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"))
                .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("text"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setLights(0x0000FF, 3000, 2000)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(56, builder.build());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Метод создания уведомления, как requestCode  решил использовать дату и время показа в миллисекундах, для уникальности

```
private void addAlarmNotification(long startTime, String title, String text){
    AlarmManager alarmManager;

    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("text", text);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int)startTime, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, alarmIntent);
}
```